# select all users who have participated in all elections

Tags: sql

I have database structure as

```
User Table(user id, username, first name,last name)

Event Table(event id,event name, event date)

UserEvent(user id, event id)
```

I want to know username of all users who have participated in all events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick

```
    SELECT u.id as user_id, u.username
FROM USER U,
(
        SELECT COUNT(EVENT_ID) AS EVENT_COUNT
        FROM EVENT
        ) AS E
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT UDSER_ID, COUNT(EVENT_ID) AS EVENT_COUNT
        FROM USEREVENT
        GROUP BY USER_ID
        ) AS UE ON U.USER_ID = UE.USER_ID
WHERE E.EVENT_COUNT = UE.EVENT_COUNT
```

Comment: select all users participated in all events
SELECT u.id, u.username FROM auth_user u,
(        SELECT COUNT(id) AS EVENT_COUNT
        FROM SecureVirtualElection_event ) AS E
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT u_id_id, COUNT(e_id_id) AS EVENT_COUNT
        FROM SecureVirtualElection_userrequestpool
        GROUP BY u_id_id
        ) AS UE 
WHERE E.EVENT_COUNT = UE.EVENT_COUNT AND u.id = UE.u_id_id;

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it: select the number of distinct event IDs associated with the user and the total number of event IDs out there.

```
select *
from User u
where (
    select count(*) from (
        select distinct ue.EventId
        from UserEvent ue
        where ue.UserId=u.UserId
    )
) = (select count(*) from Event)
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea :

1) Count number of events with distinct event ids

2) For a user, count its distinct events and if the number is same, put it in the table.